# OS installation succeeds but HDD not bootable - hardware encryption?

Tags: linux, pop-os, bootable

I have an ex-corporate HP ZBook 17. A few of the BIOS options are disabled with the explanation that the HDD is "HW encrypted", which I assume means hardware encrypted. I installed [Pop! OS](https://pop.system76.com/) 22.04 with the option to wipe and format the HDD. The installation apparently completes successfully, but upon rebooting, it says the HDD is not bootable.

If the BIOS is set to native UEFI, a screen that looks like the BIOS settings tells me the HDD is not bootable. If the BIOS is set to hybrid UEFI or legacy, Intel Boot Agent is what says the HDD is not bootable.

I used the same media to install the OS on other machines with no issue.

Is the HW encryption likely in the drive itself, or in the controller? Can I disable it with a DIP switch or something? Would it make any difference to replace the HDD? I believe it's a standard form factor 2.5" disk in a caddy.

Here's the tail of the install log:

```
INFO: configuring bootloader
INFO: running "chroot" "/tmp/distinst.5ygS0OBDh7dO" "kernelstub"
"--esp-path" "/boot/efi" "--add-options" "quiet loglevel=0
systemd.show_status=false splash" "--loader" "--manage-only"
"--force-update" "--verbose"
INFO: running "chroot" "/tmp/distinst.5ygS0OBDh7dO" "update-grub"
WARN: Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
WARN: Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
WARN: Generating grub configuration file ...
WARN: Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.18.10-76051810-generic
WARN: Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.18.10-76051810-generic
INFO: configuring keyboard layout
INFO: running "chroot" "/tmp/distinst.5ygS0OBDh7dO" "localectl"
"set-x11-keymap" "us" "" ""
INFO: running "chroot" "/tmp/distinst.5ygS0OBDh7dO" "/usr/bin/env"
"-i" "SYSTEMCTL_SKIP_REDIRECT=_" "openvt" "--" "sh"
"/etc/init.d/console-setup.sh" "reload"
INFO: running "chroot" "/tmp/distinst.5ygS0OBDh7dO" "ln" "-s"
"/etc/console-setup/cached_UTF-8_del.kmap.gz"
"/etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz"
INFO: re-enabling update-initramfs
INFO: running "chroot" "/tmp/distinst.5ygS0OBDh7dO" "sh" "-c" "rm
/usr/sbin/update-initramfs"
INFO: running "chroot" "/tmp/distinst.5ygS0OBDh7dO" "sh" "-c" "mv
/usr/sbin/update-initramfs.bak /usr/sbin/update-initramfs"
INFO: starting configuring bootloader step
INFO: /dev/sda: installing bootloader for Bios
INFO: running "chroot" "/tmp/distinst.5ygS0OBDh7dO" "grub-install"
"--recheck" "--target=i386-pc" "/dev/sda"
WARN: Installing for i386-pc platform.
INFO: running "chroot" "/tmp/distinst.5ygS0OBDh7dO" "update-initramfs"
"-c" "-k" "all"
INFO: update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.18.10-76051810-generic
INFO: finishing job
```

Comment: If this is really hardware encrypted, you can not simply disable this with a dipswitch. The keys will be stored in the TPM. Do you know what was on this laptop beforehand (Windows with Bitlocker)?

Comment: Many HP give boot issues where boot mode is not correct UEFI or BIOS to match how you installed UEFI or BIOS. And many give errors where UEFI boot description is not "Windows Boot Manager".  Most find updating UEFI and changing boot order in UEFI settings, not UEFI boot menu works. A few change Ubuntu description to Windows by creating new UEFI boot entry manually. Some boot a drive entry. See IV. https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win

Comment: @Panki It was Windows 10; don't know about Bitlocker. When I reset the BIOS to factory defaults, upon reboot it said it was deleting the TPM or something from the TPM. I know that hardware encryption in the drive controller was briefly popular, but from what I'm reading, it's mostly done in the drive itself. So I'm hoping I can just swap the drive.

Comment: @oldfred The accepted answer there says "Sony, HP, and many laptop vendors are hard-coded to only boot Windows." Does this mean the BIOS only looks for a specific EFI file, and probably not on a ext4 partition? I guess I need to get up to speed on UEFI. I haven't cared how a computer boots since the MBR days.

Comment: UEFI only boots from a FAT32 partition with efi,boot flags. UEFI uses GUID/partUUID to know which partition to find boot files. Normally every install has a separate folder in the ESP for boot files. Most systems seem to have UEFI that automatically finds the /EFI/Microsoft folder & will boot Windows entry, even after drive removed. Most UEFI let you use efibootmgr (as grub uses) to change boot order or create UEFI boot entry. HP seems to boot other installs, but default boots Windows & keeps changing it back to Windows unless you go into UEFI settings & change boot order there.

Comment: Could it be a "Secure Boot" issue? What if you boot any live Linux system and do an `fdisk -l`? If a valid partition table is being displayed, the issue won't be disk encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of invalidates my question since my assumption about what was wrong turned out to be wrong. The problem is intrinsic to Pop! OS, apparently unrelated to the hardware encryption mentioned by my BIOS.

I installed stock Ubuntu 22.04 and everything worked perfectly. I installed Ubuntu with native UEFI and even enabled SecureBoot because I read that many BIOS manufacturers include Ubuntu's signing keys. (Keep in mind that I tried Pop! OS with native UEFI, hybrid UEFI, and legacy, all with SecureBoot disabled as per Pop! OS instructions.)

The key difference seems to be that the Ubuntu installer's "erase disk" option sets up `/dev/sda1` as a `vfat` partition mounted as `/boot/efi` and `/dev/sda2` as an `ext4` partition mounted as `/`. The Pop! OS "erase disk" option only creates `/dev/sda1` as an `ext4` partition mounted as `/`. This is strange since Pop! is an Ubuntu derivative. I also don't understand why this partition scheme didn't work in legacy mode.